# Samba 4.16 integration with openldap 2.6 on Centos8 for 2FA

Tags: ldap, openldap, samba, two-factor-authentication

I want to set up 2factor authentication for both Linux and windows machines and want to manage the password via LDAP server.

For this, I am using LDAP(which provides TOTP functionality) to authenticate Linux machines and Samba for windows machines.

My LDAP server is configured and I am able to access Linux server with 2FA authentication (userpasswd + TOTP)

Samba is also running fine and I am able to access windows server with samba user password (as samba doesn't provide TOTP functionality).

Now, I don't know how to set up the integration between LDAP and samba. so that any user created in LDAP with password ( user pwd string + totp ) can be used as samba user to login to windows machines. Basically, samba user can authenticate with LDAP server with TOTP password.

Here is my slapd.conf and samba file

***cat etc/openldap/slapd.conf***

```
<br>
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema<br>
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema<br>
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema<br>
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema<br>
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/samba.schema<br>
<br>
pidfile /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid<br>
argsfile /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args<br>
<br>
modulepath /usr/local/libexec/openldap<br>
moduleload pw-totp.so<br>
password-hash {TOTP1ANDPW}<br>
<br>
database mdb<br>
maxsize 1073741824<br>
suffix "dc=antares,dc=net"<br>
rootdn "cn=Manager,dc=antares,dc=net"<br>
rootpw secret<br>
directory /usr/local/var/openldap-data<br>
index objectClass eq<br>
overlay totp<br>
database monitor<br>
<br>
TLSCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/openldap/server_cert.pem<br>
TLSCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/openldap/server_cert.pem<br>
TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/openldap/server_key.pem<br>
----------------------<br>
<br>
<br>
```

```
***cat /usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf<br>***
[global]<br>
netbios name = LDAPSRV<br>
realm = ANTARES.NET<br>
server role = active directory domain controller<br>
workgroup = ANTARES<br>
idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes<br>
        security = user<br>
        passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://192.168.1.86:3389/<br>
        ldap suffix = dc=antares,dc=net<br>
        ldap admin dn = cn=Manager,dc=antares,dc=net<br>
        ldap passwd sync = yes<br>
        ldap ssl = no<br>
<br>
[sysvol]<br>
path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol<br>
read only = No<br>
<br>
[netlogon]<br>
path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol/antares.net/scripts<br>
read only = No'''<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do this will not work. You cannot use openldap as a backend for a Samba AD DC, you should remove all the lines that you added to the smb.conf that the provision created. You cannot just sync users etc between an openldap server and a Samba AD DC, you can use a script to extract the users etc from AD and then create them in openldap and there is a way to sync passwords from AD to openldap, see 'samba-tool user syncpasswords --help' for more info.